# Custom table cell wont scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cell

Hi I am working with a custom cell.  But i can't get the dang thing to scroll. It displays the right content, I have set the cell height and seem to have the correct options checked for the table view like scrolling enabled and bounce but nothing. Included is some of the code. Any help would be super great.

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "StudentListTableViewCell.h"


@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController


{
    NSArray *NameLabel;
    NSArray *ProgrammeLabel;
    NSArray *CourseLabel;


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Change button color
    //_sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.96f alpha:0.2f];

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];



    // Initialize Name
    NameLabel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sung Tepper", @"Hannah  Zetterberg", @"January Orduna", @"Obdulia Rambin", @"Marhta Mcgonigal", @"Scarlett Bardsley", @"Sung Tepper", @"Hannah  Zetterberg", @"January Orduna", @"Obdulia Rambin", @"Marhta Mcgonigal", @"Scarlett Bardsley", nil];

    ProgrammeLabel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", @"SABET 2014", nil];

    // Initialize Course
    CourseLabel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"BP12", @"BP12", @"BP12", @"BP12", @"BP12", @"BP12",@"BP12", @"BP12", @"BP12",@"BP12", @"BP12", @"BP12", nil];

    self.title = @"News";

    [super viewDidLoad];    

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [NameLabel count];



}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *StudentListTableViewCellIdentifier = @"StudentListCell";

    StudentListTableViewCell *cell = (StudentListTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:StudentListTableViewCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StudentListCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    cell.NameLabel.text = [NameLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.ProgrammeLabel.text = [ProgrammeLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.CourseLabel.text = [CourseLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"man60.jpg"];


    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}

@end
```

Comment: Cells don't scroll unless you have a scrollview within a cell. Are you saying your tableView as a whole isn't scrolling? If so, are you sure you aren't intercepting any taps? Make sure user interaction is enabled on your tableView and cell?

Comment: The only reason that the table view isn't scrolling is that something's blocking the input. Also, you should stay true to apple's naming conventions and name objects with lowercase like `NSArray *nameLabel`.

Comment: Try commenting out the `panGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Add scroll view in your custom cell that way you would get the scroll but my advice would be to avoid scroll within a tableview. A scroll within a scroll is not a good design from user perspective. At end, it's your call !

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments and suggestions. Yes I have a table view and that isn't scrolling - interaction is enabled on both. Naming conventions noted and changed - thanks. Commenting out the PanGesture had no effect. I'll try adding the scroll view in the custom cell see what happens. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is created because of your panGestureRecognizer, which doesn't pass touches on to the tableview.

This should fix it - add this method to your `MainViewController.m`

```
  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
        UIView *touchedView = touch.view;

//check if the touch was received by table view
        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [touchedView class]] rangeOfString:@"UITableView"].location != NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Don't forget to set the delegate of your gestureRecognizer to `self`, and implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

In your `viewDidLoad` method, set your class as the delegate of the gestureRecognizer:

```
self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

In the `MainViewController.h` file, do this to implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate:

```
@interface MainViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Comment: Thanks Vinod. I'll give it a go. So I should place this code under my panGestureRecognixer? Also could you please tip me on how I implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.